# Maximum and minimum when $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)= 0 = \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ continuous function, such that $f(0)=1$ and 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)= 0 = \lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x).$$

Show that $f$ gets its maximum value in $\mathbb R$. Does $f$ necessarily reach its minimum?

My thoughts:

I don't know what the last question is about, its continuous so why wouldn't it?

How can I seek its maximum? Should I think that the function is between $1$ and $0$ so that its maximum is $f(0)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all note that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ satisfies the hypothesis but it attains no minimal value in $\mathbb{R}$.

As regards the maximum value, by the definition of limit,
$$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} f(x)= 0$$
implies that there is $R>0$ such that  $|f(x)|<1/2$ for all $|x|>R$ (here $1/2$ can be replaced by any real number less that $1=|f(0)|$).

Show that the maximum value of $f$ in the closed and bounded set $[-R,R]$ (here we use the continuity of $f$) is actually the maximum value for the whole real line.

This maximum value need not to be $f(0)=1$. Take for example $f(x)=\frac{2}{(x-1)^2+1}$ which satisfies the hypothesis but its maximum value in $\mathbb{R}$ is $f(1)=2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise in how to use definitions.

Break it into two parts, a finite and an infinite as follows: Let $\epsilon = 0.5$. There exists an $r>0$, such that $|f(x)|<0.5$ whenever $|x| > r$, by the definition of $\lim _{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Now, consider the set $\{|x| \leq r\}$. This is closed and bounded, hence compact. Therefore, on this set, $f(x)$ *attains it's maximum* as it is continuous on the set. However, since $f(0)=1$, the maximum over $|x|<r$ of $f$ is in fact the maximum over $\mathbb{R}$, since that value is greater than $0.5$.

As far the minimum is concerned, we cannot say anything, since a function like $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ would cause a problem, for example. It satisfies the constraints, but doesn't attain a minimum, because it slowly dips to zero.

Note that we can't say where the maximum is, because we can't say anything about $r$, and the theorem about continuous functions on compact sets only gives an existence, it does not pinpoint the maximum itself. To do that, you would need derivatives for a good estimate.